# javascript not loading in a dynamic iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I've spent hours reading javascript books, patterns and looking on stackoverflow questions but I'm stuck on loading something dynamically into an iframe

**Goal** Click on a button, (1) ajax post to `temp.php` with data (ex. src, height, width, id).
(2) `temp.php` sets up the iframe and returns the respective html. (3) Javascript prepends the data.

Here is the respective code I have so far

(1)

```
$.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           data:{
                 'src':"target.php",
                 'frame_height':$(".mydiv").height(),
                 'frame_width':$(".mydiv").width()
           },
           url:"temp.php",
           success:function (inHtml) {
                 loadConversation(inHtml,
```

I've loaded the POST variables into the respective php variables already.
(2)

```
<iframe id="myTestFrame" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>"
    height="<?php echo $height; ?>" frameborder="0">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
```

(3)
`$('.mydiv').prepend(inHtml);`

Please assume that the syntax is done correctly.

the `target.php` does run a simple javascript code initializing a scroll plugin:

```
$(function () {

    var Scroll = (function () {

        var  init = function () {

             $("#content-1").mCustomScrollbar({});

             $(".inner_content").mCustomScrollbar({autoDraggerLength:true});                      

             $(".output a[rel~='_mCS_1_scrollTo']").click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $("#content-1").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", $(this).attr("href"));
             });
             };

        return { init:init };

    })();

    Scroll.init();
});
```

What's happening now is that I can call temp.php directly from the webserver and it will load properly.

[expected](http://imageshack.us/a/img203/4990/help1x.jpg)

But once it's called from the main site - it breaks (and an 'undefined' to boot)

[broken in main site](http://imageshack.us/a/img585/9578/help2r.jpg)

I've done the same iframe post and then update src dynamically with another php page with a plugin and it works fine (same on click, ajax post, prepend(html) , I'm completely lost). The main site is running it inside a tabbed interface from jquery UI, but I don't think that makes any difference - what I've found so far is that if I insert a simple 'alert(document.height)' into the init function, the alert box will contain 0, so I think the javascript runs before the iframe has finished loading - but Firebug shows that the Response HTML in NET is perfectly fine and the code is rather short. (The script is placed last right before the close  brace)

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: nothing in the firebug console - the combination seems to work fine on Chrome and the error is in Firefox which makes me think I'm leaving out some small tweak somewhere

Comment: try jQuery instead $, like that, jQuery(window).load(function($) { ... }; jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... }